# Erro de diretório no Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Apaguei a pasta onde havia os projetos e não consegui mais criar nenhum projeto.

[image: screen shot da tela]

Comment: Tenta apagar as duas pastas .gradle/ e .androidstudio/ na tua pasta de usuário.

Comment: apaguei e continua o mesmo erro Cigano. Continua mesmo criando outro projeto e criando em outra pasta.

Comment: Ok, qual versão do Android Studio estás a utilizar?

Comment: versão 1.3 Anderson

Comment: Vá em ```Help -> Show log``` e mostre o que ele diz lá. Deve ter alguma informação mais detalhada ou até explicação de como resolver o problema.